# Contact form doesn't function

Tags: html, css, codepen

I am working with Blogger and I am a beginner. I want to add this contact form to my website: https://codepen.io/JonLehman/pen/yOdbOG

I can add it, but how can I let it function? I think that I need to add something in the html to send the written text to my email address? Thank you

```css
body {
  background-color: #444442;
  padding-top: 85px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif, 'arial';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'arial';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #9b9b9b;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/* ///// inputs /////*/

input:focus~label,
textarea:focus~label,
input:valid~label,
textarea:valid~label {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #999;
  top: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.225s ease;
  transition: all 0.225s ease;
}

.styled-input {
  float: left;
  width: 293px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .styled-input {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.styled-input label {
  color: #999;
  padding: 1.3rem 30px 1rem 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.styled-input.wide {
  width: 650px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

input,
textarea {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

input:focus~span,
textarea:focus~span {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.075s ease;
  transition: all 0.075s ease;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 15em;
}

.input-container {
  width: 650px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto 25px auto;
}

.submit-btn {
  float: right;
  padding: 7px 35px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4b8cfb;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.submit-btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .submit-btn {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>contact us</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h4 style="text-align:center">We'd love to hear from you!</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row input-container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="styled-input wide">
        <input type="text" required />
        <label>Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="styled-input">
        <input type="text" required />
        <label>Email</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="styled-input" style="float:right;">
        <input type="text" required />
        <label>Phone Number</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="styled-input wide">
        <textarea required></textarea>
        <label>Message</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn-lrg submit-btn">Send Message</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't send an email from the client/browser directly without going through some kind of mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Php. There are many great tutorials but here's one that's not too complex.

https://www.codexworld.com/create-simple-contact-form-php-send-email/

Feel free to ask questions if you get lost. You will need to have access to something like XAAMP or a server to test your work.

your PHP should look something like this.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
$myemail = 'yourEmailGoesHere';
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Enter a subject");
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}
$message = "
Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject
Message:
$message
";
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
header('Location: thanks.php');
exit();
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}
function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>
  <p>FAIL! Please correct the following error:</p>
  <strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
  <p>You may close this window and try again</p>
</body>
 </html>
 <?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a contact form, with any css code you want, is with google spreadsheet api. You must have only a public published google spreadsheet, you use a html form that send data to this spreadsheet and is like contact blogger form, but i think is better because you have a real time note for a comment.... With blogger contact form that recently used, it's not working, but also i know that emails receiving is done a specific time of the day...